# Equivalent measures share almost surely properties?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I feel like this statement is true, but my inability to find a concrete statement of it is forcing me to second-guess myself.

**Context:**

I have a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, a bounded, strictly positive random variable $\infty>\Theta>0$, then define the probability measure $Q$, using $\Theta$ as my Radon-Nikodym derivative,
$$
dP = \Theta dQ
$$
It should be the case that that these measures are equivalent $Q \sim P$ in a measure theoretic sense:
$$
0 = P(A) = \int_A \Theta dQ \iff Q(A) = 0
$$

**Actual problem:**

Suppose $A \in \mathcal{F}$ is some event which holds $P$-almost surely, then if $Q \sim P$ it also holds $Q$-almost surely.

*Proof:*

$P(A)=1 \iff P(A^c) = 0 \iff Q(A^c) =0 \iff Q(A) = 1$

Is this true?

Comment: Yes, it is true.

Comment: If $Q(A)=0$, then $P(A)=0$ by the definition of the integral. Assume that $P(A)=0$. Then, for all $m\geq0$, $0=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_{A\cap\{1/n>\Theta\geq 1/(n+1)}\Theta\geq Q(A\cap\{1/m>\Theta\geq 1/(m+1))\frac{1}{m+1}$, where we are denoting $1/0=+\infty$. Then $Q(A\cap\{1/m>\Theta\geq 1/(m+1))=0$ for all $m$. It follows that $Q(A)=\sum_mQ(A\cap\{1/m>\Theta\geq 1/(m+1))=0$.